# is it posssible to access a PCI memory without writting a kernel mode driver?

Tags: windows, kernel, device-driver

I need to access memory on a PCI device and responding to its interrupts in windows (32bit and 64 bit on 7 and above)

Can I do this without writing a kernel device driver?

Can I write a user mode driver for this task?

Comment: Kernel driver required.

Comment: @HansPassant: are you sure?  That was my immediate reaction too, but see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for example.  Aslo http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn376882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which lists DMA among other things only supported by kernel drivers ... but not memory mapped I/O or interrupt handling.